# Any way to tell if a floated element has been bumped down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

Imagine a responsive menu where the the elements are set to float. They're all, say, 150px wide. As the menu is reduced in width, individual elements will, one by one, get bumped down to the next row.

You're trying to determine whether an element has been bumped down. My thought was to design things in such a way where I could find out if the top of the floated element!= 0. If not, it's been bumped down to the next row. I could also evaluate element heights to figure out if an element is in row 2, 3, etc.

Is there a simpler way to determine if a floated element has been wrapped/bumped down due to parent width constraints?

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle by trying to do this. What is your actual problem? What you've asked is how to figure out a solution to the problem that you think will fix your original problem, if you can get it to work. If flexbox is available to you, (IE10+, Android 4.4+), then that will be your golden goose.

Comment: Are you checking via JS or CSS?  There are options in CSS for nth-of-type and in JS you can capture based on class and loop through the array of elements returned.

Comment: @Adam, I disagree.  The question "How can I tell when a floated element wraps" is pretty straight-forward and concise.  The only thing left out is what the OP intends to do with the result, which may or may not be important.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Looqa4/ What row are each of these blocks in as you collapse the screen? The longer the OP spends trying to solve his layout problem with flawed JS, the more time he will waste.

Comment: @Adam, the purpose is to add menu separators, but with a ability to hide the first and last ones from each row. CSS selectors won't work because the `first-child- or `nth-of-type` can change, based on the width of the container.

Comment: @BenjaminAllison - I'd love to help, but I can't really envision what you mean. If you could reproduce a simple `jsfiddle` with just your test case, I could understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Since your elements are a fixed size, 150px, you can simply use some math to figure out where they are at in the container element.

floor(container width / element width) = number of elements per line

element index % element per line = column

floor(element index / elements per line) = row

Simply add an event listener for the containers resize event and do your check there.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find offset of element f.e. this way:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $(".some-menu-item-selector").each(function(e) {
       elementOffset = $(this).offset().top,
       $(this).html(elementOffset); 
    });
});
```

Now when I have offsets I can group elements by "rows". There is only one assumption: elements have same height. If not, thing gets complicated.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do it, but it is one possibility using javascript or jQuery.

You can get the position from the top of the first menu item, then check the distance for the next elements. if they are different, you would know that the the element has been displaced.

You would have to do this on load and on window change.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know very little JS but you can check height. I'm using a menu for an example to addClass or removeClass.

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/gapaqe/1/

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

    if ($('nav').height() >= 62) {

        $('nav').addClass('test');

    } else {

        $('nav').removeClass('test');


    }

}).resize();
```

**CSS**

```
nav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.test a {
    background: blue
}
/* to clear the floats all fast like dude */
nav {
    display: table;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
    <a href="#">Link 9</a>
  </nav>
```